# Designing an anti-static enclosure for sensitive electronics

Tags: esd, antistatic

I was a little disappointed to discover that I managed to fry a brand new Raspberry Pi camera module. After testing on multiple hardware and triple checking all the connectors, I was forced to conclude that I fried the module on board through static discharge.

[image: Pi Camera module]

Since then, I've ordered another one but I'm concerned I will also eventually kill the new one (these modules are particularly sensitive to static discharge) so I am thinking of buying or making some sort of enclosure for the module to help protect the sensitive electronics on board.

I understand there are precautions that should be taken when handling sensitive electronics such as wearing a earthed anti-static wrist-strap or touching a earthed water tap prior to handling.

However, what about when the device is installed? For example, will a plastic case build up enough static charge that will eventually discharge through the module? Should an enclosure be made of metal (and tied to the ground pin)? Will it be sufficient protection if I cut up pieces of an anti-static bag and wrap it around the module?

What are some measures I can take to prevent static discharge from being a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a good candidate for an Altoids tin (or other small metal enclosure - those just happen to be a handy size and common in the world currently - some decades ago it would be the pipe tobacco tins my great-uncle used.)

Mind you, most devices are far less sensitive when fully constructed than when loose parts. But if you think it's particularly sensitive, might as well use a metal box (you can of course, use a die-cast electronic project box if little tin boxes upset your stomach - but they cost more and don't come full of sweets.)

Answer (score 0):

Loose components are very sensitive to electrostatic discharge.

Once installed on a board, the power supply circuit protects the electronics.

Use paper surfaces rather than plastic when unboxing sensitive parts.  Do not handle parts in extremely dry (static) conditions without taking proper precautions.  (unwrap and install the part in the bathroom after taking a shower, lol.)

c-:

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. It is kinda pointless to answer to an (already answered) question of one year ago. Please concentrate your efforts in newer or unanswered questions